# Core Plot - Histogram

Tags: iphone, ios, core-plot

How could I realize a Histogram with corePlot.
Actually I am trying that by using a Bar Chart.

Is in the Bar-Chart any option to group my values.
For example:
so i can print just 3 bars.
So that the values should group like this:

```
 
  X

 0...5: Barline 1

 6...10:Barline 2 

11...15:Barline 3
```

Is in CorePlot-Bar any property to do that?

thnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you'll have to pre-process your data and do the grouping yourself before passing the data to Core Plot.